# PHP Script doesn't work. While Condition inside a Loop

Tags: php, html

I hope somebody can help me here. I am just coding a little bit and I am stuck. A tip would be great, which explains to me, where I am wrong.

The task is kind of more complex, than what I am doing right now. At the moment, I want the for loop to check every substring of a string. Inside the loop is a while condition, which should keep echoing out the substrings, till a substring is a space. Then it should stop echoing out.

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I get a TimeOut on my server.

```
<?php
// Task
// Find-and-Replace
// "whole word" match
// Text is sorted as array of character

$text = "This film is the best film of the year."; // Find: film, replace: movie
$word = "film";
$replace = "movie";
echo strlen($text) . "<br>";

for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($text); $i++){
    while(substr($text,$i,1) != " ") {
        echo substr($text,0,1);
    }
}



?>
```

Edit:
It still does not work:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($text); $i++){
    while(substr($text,$i,1) != " ") {
        echo substr($text,$i,1);
    }
}
```

Without the While loop it iterates through every letter. But it will not work with the whileloop.

Comment: It will never exit the while loop to start. On the first iteration it is going to check the *same* substring over and over and over and over. You should try this with just the for loop...

Comment: You're not incrementing $i in the while loop, so you're always comparing the first character against space.... perhaps change the `while` to an `if`, though I'm not completely clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Are you just looking to replace all instances of the word "film" with the world "movie"?

Comment: Thanks. I saw that I forgot the $i in the while loop. But it still doesn't work. I'll try to use an if condition instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier with regular expressions:

```
$text = "This film is the best film of the year."; // Find: film, replace: movie
$word = "/film/i";
$replace = "movie";

echo preg_replace($word, $replace , $text );
```

Comment: Thank you. I could have done it with str_replace too, but I am trying to do it completely without string manipulation functions. I updated my code... and it still does not work :( Thank you anyway.

Comment: This works just fine for me, I tested it.  Why are you trying to avoid string manipulations?

Comment: Because I am making a "think like a programmer" course. This is why. So you say, my updated code works fine for you? Weird and strange simultaniously.

Comment: Because this is a homework question, I can't give you the exact answer.  You should probably approach the problem like this.  1) does the next N characters match the string?  2) if true remove N characters and replace with $replace 3) if false, bump by 1

Comment: It isn't actually 'homework'. It is just a book I bought and I am trying stuff, I guess I am not supposed to try yet... none the less. Thanks for the input.